# Print list in table format in python

Tags: python, tabular

I am trying to print several lists (equal length) as columns of an table.

I am reading data from a .txt file, and at the end of the code, I have 5 lists, which I would like to print as columns separated but space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing tabular data in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122347/printing-tabular-data-in-python)

Comment: For fancy gui display, you could use PyQt, a QTableWidget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll show you a 3-list analog:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> l3 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> for row in zip(l1, l2, l3):
...     print ' '.join(row)

a 1 x
b 2 y
c 3 z
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use my package [beautifultable](https://github.com/pri22296/beautifultable) . It supports adding data by rows or columns or even mixing both the approaches. You can insert, remove, update any row or column.

### Usage

```
>>> from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
>>> table = BeautifulTable()
>>> table.column_headers = ["name", "rank", "gender"]
>>> table.append_row(["Jacob", 1, "boy"])
>>> table.append_row(["Isabella", 1, "girl"])
>>> table.append_row(["Ethan", 2, "boy"])
>>> table.append_row(["Sophia", 2, "girl"])
>>> table.append_row(["Michael", 3, "boy"])
>>> print(table)
+----------+------+--------+
|   name   | rank | gender |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Jacob   |  1   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
| Isabella |  1   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Ethan   |  2   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Sophia  |  2   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
| Michael  |  3   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
```

Have fun

Answer (score 2):

Assming that you have a lists of lists:

```
for L in list_of_lists:
    print " ".join(L)
```

The `str.join(iterable)` function, joins the components of an iterable by the string given.

Therefore, `" ".join([1, 2, 3])` becomes "1 2 3".

In case I might have misunderstood the question and each `list` is supposed to be a column:

```
for T in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5):
    print " ".join(T)
```

`zip()` merges the given lists to one list of tuples:

```
>>> zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
for nested_list in big_container_list
    print '\t'.join(nested_list)
```

with `\t` being the tabulation character

quick example:

```
In [1]: a = [['1','2'],['3','4']]
In [5]: for nested_list in a:
...:     print '\t'.join(nested_list)
...: 
1       2
3       4
```

Comment: He wants each sublist to be a *column*, not a row.

Comment: Didn't understand the question properly, then, I suppose. I'm still not sure what he means, though, but it seems I'm the only one that understood this :/

Answer (score 0):

Try out my [library](https://github.com/SuperMaZingCoder/TableIt)

NOTE: This answer is already posted on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data/59469272#59469272), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483498/print-table-in-python/59469626#59469626).

I just made a library for this that I think could really help. It is extremely simple, that's why I think you should use it. It is called **TableIT**.

### Basic Use

To use it, first follow the download instructions on the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/SuperMaZingCoder/TableIt).

Then import it:

```py
import TableIt
```

Then make a list of lists where each inner list is a row:

```py
table = [
    [4, 3, "Hi"],
    [2, 1, 808890312093],
    [5, "Hi", "Bye"]
]
```

Then all you have to do is print it:

```py
TableIt.printTable(table)
```

This is the output you get:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| 4            | 3            | Hi           |
| 2            | 1            | 808890312093 |
| 5            | Hi           | Bye          |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

### Field Names

You can use field names if you want to (**if you aren't using field names you don't have to say useFieldNames=False because it is set to that by default**):

```py
TableIt.printTable(table, useFieldNames=True)
```

From that you will get:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| 4            | 3            | Hi           |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2            | 1            | 808890312093 |
| 5            | Hi           | Bye          |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

There are other uses to, for example you could do this:

```py
import TableIt

myList = [
    ["Name", "Email"],
    ["Richard", "richard@fakeemail.com"],
    ["Tasha", "tash@fakeemail.com"]
]

TableIt.print(myList, useFieldNames=True)
```

From that:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Name                  | Email                 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| Richard               | richard@fakeemail.com |
| Tasha                 | tash@fakeemail.com    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Or you could do:

```py
import TableIt

myList = [
    ["", "a", "b"],
    ["x", "a + x", "a + b"],
    ["z", "a + z", "z + b"]
]

TableIt.printTable(myList, useFieldNames=True)
```

And from that you get:

```
+-----------------------+
|       | a     | b     |
+-------+-------+-------+
| x     | a + x | a + b |
| z     | a + z | z + b |
+-----------------------+
```

### Colors

You can also use colors.

You use colors by using the color option (**by default it is set to None**) and specifying RGB values.

Using the example from above:

```py
import TableIt

myList = [
    ["", "a", "b"],
    ["x", "a + x", "a + b"],
    ["z", "a + z", "z + b"]
]

TableIt.printTable(myList, useFieldNames=True, color=(26, 156, 171))
```

Then you will get:

[image]

Please note that printing colors might not work for you but it does works the exact same as the other libraries that print colored text. I have tested and every single color works. The blue is not messed up either as it would if using the default `34m` ANSI escape sequence (if you don't know what that is it doesn't matter). Anyway, it all comes from the fact that every color is RGB value rather than a system default.

### More Info

For more info check the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/SuperMaZingCoder/TableIt)